# ASP.NET MVC: Redirect from query string params to a canonical url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

In my Asp.Net Mvc project I'd like to have a good looking urls, e.g. mysite.com/Page2, and I want to redirect from my old style urls (such as mysite.com?page=2) with 301 state so that there won't be two urls with identical content. Is there a way to do it?

As far as I know Asp.Net binding framework doesn't make difference between query string and curly brace params

Comment: how are the true ASP.NET pages named?

Comment: user49223, well I don't think it makes sence, but here is an example: /Article/1022/Ms-Sharepoint-Setup-Manual/Page2. Page2 here is paging for displaying comments for this article. At this moment this url looks that way: /Article/1022/Ms-Sharepoint-Setup-Manual?page=2

Comment: I am not sure this will provide the SEO benefit you think it will. Page1 and Page2 if only changing the comments section of the page will still have largely the same content on it.

Comment: Chris Sainty, yes, in this particular example this will not provide any visible SEO profit, I wrote it because of its simplicity. I agree that you probably won't want to change your routing system only for good looking paging. But if you have a url like `mysite.com/Articles?category=Sharepoint` you would like to change it to `mysite.com/Articles/Sharepoint` and the question how to do it remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as I can see performing such redirection in ASP.NET MVC might be tricky. This is how I did it:

global.asax:

```
        routes.Add(new QueryStringRoute());

        routes.MapRoute(null, "Article/{id}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Article", action = "View", page = 1 },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "Article/{id}/{name}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Article", action = "View" },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );
```

QueryStringRoute.cs:

```
public class QueryStringRoute : RouteBase
{
    private static string[] queryStringUrls = new string[]
    {
        @"~/Article/\d{1,6}/.*?page=\d{1,3}"
    };


    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string url = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;

        foreach (string queryStringUrl in queryStringUrls)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(queryStringUrl);
            if (regex.IsMatch(url))
            {
                long id = 0; /* Parse the value from regex match */
                int page = 0; /* Parse the value from regex match */
                string name = ""; /* Parse the value from regex match */

                RouteData rd = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());

                rd.Values.Add("controller", "QueryStringUrl");
                rd.Values.Add("action", "Redirect");
                rd.Values.Add("id", id);
                rd.Values.Add("page", page);
                rd.Values.Add("name", name);
                rd.Values.Add("controllerToRedirect", "Article");
                rd.Values.Add("actionToRedirect", "View");

                return rd;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

QueryStringUrlController.cs:

```
public class QueryStringUrlController : Controller
{
    public RedirectToRouteResult Redirect(long id, int page, string name,
        string controllerToRedirect, string actionToRedirect)
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent(actionToRedirect, controllerToRedirect, new { id = id, page = page, name = name });
    }
}
```

Assuming you have such routing as in my global.asax file (listed above) you can create a custom `Route` class that will handle incoming requests and map them on a special redirection controller which will then redirect them to appropriate urls with 301 state. Then you must add this route to global.asax **before** your "Article" routes

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I got your question right. It seems, your current setup relies on those GET parameters (like mysite.com?page=2). If you dont want to change this, you will have to use those parameters further. There would be no problem in doing so, though. Your users do not have to use or see them. In order to publish 'new style URLs' only, you may setup a URL redirect in your web server. That would change new style URLs to old style URLs.

The problem is the 301. If the user requests an old style URL, it would be accepted by the webserver as well. Refusing the request with a 301 error seems hard to achieve for me.

In order to get around this, I guess you will have to change your parameter scheme. You site may still rely on GET parameters - but they get a new name. Lets say, your comments are delivered propery for the following (internal) URL in the old scheme:

```
/Article/1022/Ms-Sharepoint-Setup-Manual?newpage=2
```

Note the new parameter name. In your root page (or master page, if you are using those), you may handle the redirect permanent (301) manually. Therefore, incoming 'old style requests' are distinguishable by using old parameter names. This could be used to manually assemble the 301 in the response in ASP code.

Personally, I would sugesst, to give up the 301 idea and just use URL redirection.

Comment: user492238, changing query string params is a good point, but redirecting in master page I think is not very good for an MVC project

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS 7, the [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/) should work for your scenario.